# AWS RDS Free Tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have setup an AWS EC2 instance over 12 months ago on the Free tier and it's now charging me, which is understandable since the 12 months free tier has expired for the EC2.

I am now wanting to try out the AWS RDS DB instance.

The question I like to ask is, should I be able to create the RDS 12 month free tier or will AWS charge me since it's been 12 months already since I have started using AWS ?

I have never created a RDS instance before. I have only ever used the EC2 free tier.

Anyone know if I will be able to use the free tier for the RDS or will I get charged since my AWS account is active for longer than 12 months ?

Answer (score 3):

Quote from [AWS Free Tier FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/free/free-tier-faqs/) (I highlighted the answer).

> Q: When does the AWS Free Tier expire?

> Services with a 12-month Free Tier allow customers to use the product for free up to specified limits **for one year from the date the account was created**.

Comment: I also read that as well, but wasn't aware if it was when I create my AWS account or if when I create the service free tier. I am starting to think it's when I create my AWS account and not when I create the service I want to test.

Comment: AWS explicitly says it's from the date the account was created, not from when you start to use a service.

Comment: Not answering the RDS question but if you want to keep using EC2 for free (for now) you can use T4g.micro instance with ARM64 CPU. It’s got it’s own free tier.

Comment: @MLu wouldn't that cost me now that I have used the free tier already and it has past 12 months ?

Comment: @MLu  It seems that the free trial for t4g.micro ended on 31 December.